# Node JS req.body rendering undifined

Tags: node.js, express

[image]

For some reason, while inserting the req.body. Data isn't post method wasn't complete

Comment: [Please post your code as formatted text instead of as a link to a picture of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Comment: try changing the `'application.json'` to `'application/json'` in the `content-type` header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `content-type` is incorrect.

You'll need to make it `application/json` instead of `application.json`

You can read a bit more about [Content-Types in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) as well as [MIME formats for headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) or anything else that accepts things in this format. Basically you'll rarely use a period. If ever.

If you're still getting an error after that when trying to insert your data you'll need to expand your question to include what information about how the endpoint you're trying to submit data to expect that input to be handled.